# Can't print pdf file with lpr

Tags: printing, pdf, cups

I am currently using Arch linux. I am trying to print a pdf file for the command line, it is easier that way as I need to print several range of pages.

Just for testing I issue a command to print a text file:

```
lpr a.txt
```

And it prints ok. Now I want to print the pdf file:

```
 lpr -P HP_LaserJet_2300_series 
 -o page-ranges=80-81 
 -o media=a4 
 -o sides=two-sided-long-edge 
 -o scaling=110
 "Introductory and Intermediate Algebra - Aufmann 4th.pdf"
```

When I issue `lpq` this is the result:

```
HP_LaserJet_2300_series is ready
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                           Total Size 
1st     alber   321     Introductory and Intermediate A   32868352 bytes
```

So the file is in the queue but is not printing and there are no processing jobs on the printer either.

I then access CUPS web interface. I look at state of the pending jobs and the following message appears:

```
stopped  "Exception: /var/spool/cups/d00321-001 
(file position 32580806): unknown token while reading object (PDF)"
```

Comment: Does `lpr "Introductory and Intermediate Algebra - Aufmann 4th.pdf"` print? Does `lpr -P HP_LaserJet_2300_series a.txt` print?

Comment: @slm No. It adds a queue but not printing:              `2nd     alber   322     Introductory and Intermediate A 32868352 bytes`

Comment: What about: `lpr -P HP_LaserJet_2300_series a.txt`?

Comment: @slm lpr -P HP_LaserJet_2300_series a.txt prints ok, but still can't print the pdf file.

Comment: Sounds like the driver for the printer cannot handle PDF directly. Is this printer being hosted via CUPS?

Comment: @slm CUPS is installed on my linux box. I don't know whether the printer is being hosted via CUPS. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: If you change the name of the PDF file to say `a.pdf` and repeat the `lpr` test using that name does it work? Knowing who hosts the printer is easiest to determine via the web U/I as you tried.

Comment: @slm I rename the file, but still not working.

Comment: OK, any additional info from `lpstat -a -p` and checking the log file `/var/log/cups/error_log`?

Comment: Please post (in the question) `/etc/cups/printers.conf`. Also, please look in `/var/log/cups`. Check particularly `access.log` and `errors.log` for anything that looks relevant. Also look at `page.log`.

Comment: Maybe you should just buy the book.

Comment: @JoeHass I got the book already, I am only printing the exercise pages.